Reset modem using a batch file
I have this command lines to reset the modem:
telnet 192.168.1.1
password: *******
dev reboot
sys reboot

and here is batch file script:
@echo off
telnet 192.168.1.1

output is:

With this code, it remains to getting password, but I don't know how to give password inside the code and not to give in runtime.
How can I do this?

You really can't script the standard telnet client that comes with Windows. But, you can with Albert Yale's Telenet Scripting Tool.

Auto Input UserName And Password While Run Telnet
Actually this is not pure batch, but a combination of batch and VBScript.
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set #VBS="%Temp%\autologin.vbs"
set #CMN=Set Shel=CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^): ^
Shel.Run "cmd /c telnet 192.168.1.1": ^
WScript.Sleep 2000: ^
Shel.SendKeys "your username": ^
Shel.SendKeys "{ENTER}": ^
WScript.Sleep 2000: ^
Shel.SendKeys "your passwd": ^
Shel.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
echo !#CMN! >!#VBS!
call !#VBS!
endlocal

Or simple only use VBS, without batch.
Save this as vbs file e.g. autolog.vbs:
Set Shel=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shel.Run "cmd /c telnet 192.168.1.1"
WScript.Sleep 2000
Shel.SendKeys "your username"
Shel.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 2000
Shel.SendKeys "your passwd"
Shel.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 

Just double-click to execute, like batch file.
Hope this helpful

References:
SendKeys statement
ShellExecute method

I'm getting error, the error text is: object required: 'shel', code : 800A01A8

I forget, input the ... in user, pass, host according yours. I've tried. worked.

yes I did it before. do I need to change TVBS?

Sorry. i missed litte text in VBS Set Shel=.... Updated.

@Unique631 Vbscript has started its deprecation so you may want to find a long term solution in the near future.  If you search for Powershell and Telnet, you should find some solutions using that.

it's far better to use a hybrid batch/VBS or hybrid batch/Js solution rather than doing something tricky and unreadable like that

@phuclv Great idea. I don't understand about that yet. I'll study it. Thanks.

@Mr.Key7 solved. I appreciate. I got error because I used }!{*()#@^ inside the password. I removed these characters and it worked. so is there any way to use special chars?

@Unique631 If the password uses special characters, some of them sometimes need to be escaped. you can learn it in https://ss64.com/vb/

This piece of code fixed the problem:
Set Shel=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shel.Run "cmd /c telnet 192.168.1.1"
WScript.Sleep 2000
Shel.SendKeys "passworddkjfhkds38kjh"
Shel.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 

it can't send special characters in password.
